# std::array of a private nested struct can't be initialized (error C2248)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

The following code compiles correctly in ideone (C++14, [link](http://ideone.com/reV0IC)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    void foo() { auto stashedCells = cells; }
private:
    struct Bar { std::vector<int> choices; };
    std::array<Bar, 10> cells;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.foo();
}
```

However, in Visual Studio 2015, it produces the following errors:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\array(220): error C2248: 'Foo::Bar': cannot access private struct declared in class 'Foo'
1>  c:\users\alcedine\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mvce\mvce\main.cpp(9): note: see declaration of 'Foo::Bar'
1>  c:\users\alcedine\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mvce\mvce\main.cpp(5): note: see declaration of 'Foo'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\array(220): note: This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::array<Foo::Bar,10>::array(const std::array<Foo::Bar,10> &)'
```

The unit compiles successfully if `Foo::Bar` is empty or contains just an `int`, so it doesn't seem to be due to the access specifier, compiler messages to that effect notwithstanding.

Is this due to some difference between C++11 and C++14? Is Visual Studio behaving correctly here?

Comment: Compiles fine with GCC 4.8.2 with `--std=c++11`` flag.

Comment: @SashaPachev Likewise, compiles fine with GCC 5.2.0 with either `--std=c++11` and `--std=c++14` flags.

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Replacing the array with a  `std::vector<Bar> cells{10};`
works well.

Comment: Strangely though, replaceing std::array with boost::array produces exactly the same error (also related to the copy constructor of the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug of MSVC2015.

The problem is related to the copy construction of the array that you make in `foo()`.  It seems not directly related to the implementation of `std::array`, because `boost::array` produces exactly the same error.

A workaround is to split the construction from the copy, for example:

```
void foo()
{
    decltype(cells) stashedCells;   // this works 
    stashedCells = cells;           // this works 
}
```

Or:

```
void foo()
{
    std::array<Bar, 10> stashedCells; 
    stashedCells = cells;
}
```

Other potential workarounds such as using a public `typedef` or type alias for the array and/or `Bar` always fail.  The error only disapears when making `Bar` public.